# You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity in zendesk sdk

Tags: android, zendesk

I am using external activity of zendesk sdk in my android application

I just open it using the following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ContactUsActivity.this, ContactZendeskActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then I got the following crash

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.forsale.forsale/com.zendesk.sdk.feedback.ui.ContactZendeskActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3149)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:331)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:300)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:264)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:130)
at com.zendesk.sdk.feedback.ui.ContactZendeskActivity.onCreate(ContactZendeskActivity.java:103)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)
... 10 more
```

can anyone please tell me what to do?

**EDIT**

I know that I need to use this theme in the activity, but the activity is not part of my code, it is part of zendesk sdk, and it is not defined in my manifest file, and I don't want to use this theme for my whole application

Comment: What does this message `You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.` tell you?

Comment: Yes I know that I need to use this theme in the activity, but the activity is not part of my code, it is part of zendesk sdk, and it is not defined in my manifest file, and I don't want to use this theme for my whole application.

Comment: As the message explains clearly, you can use that theme `with this activity.` only, if so you wish and don't care for UI continuity

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do one of two things:

1) Redefine the activity in your own manifest

```
<activity
  android:name="com.zendesk.sdk.feedback.ui.ContactZendeskActivity"
  android:label="@string/contact_fragment_title"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
  android:theme="your_theme" />
```

2) Subclass the activity and define the style in your Activity.

Comment: Will try both solutions and let you know, Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you very much, the first solution works with me :)